# Adding a new module to a production Magento 2 site

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade

In all of the "deployment" threads  have read, nothing seems to incorporate how to go about adding a new module into the mix.

When adding a new module that, in most cases, would add new database tables, how are you supposed to incorporate that into any of these deployment strategies?

They all talk about minimal downtime by performing compilation and static file production on a staging server, which is fine, but what doesn't add up for me (yet) is how to go about adding a new module to the website using any of these deployment strategies? I am not deploying a new site, my site is live and running, and minimal downtime would be ideal so we can continue taking orders while the updated website is prepared.

In some examples I have read, they clone the database, perform setup:upgrade etc, and then rsync files to the live site (or slight variations of this). But what about the new module database tables, which are still not in the live site database?

Can someone fill in the gaps for me here as I don't get it :-)

Comment: Adding a new module is part of the compilation process. Really depends on how you doing your live deployments, you can use something like Jenkins to automate deployment.

Comment: But if compilation happens on a staging server, how are the new modules database tables added into the live database? Nobody seems to answer this specific question for me?

Comment: Live and staging servers are two different things. Normally staging servers are just a place for UAT and QA

Comment: I am aware they are two different things. I guess nobody has an answer...

Comment: Like I said in my first comment new modules are part of the compilation process. Meaning for new module database tables to be added on live you will need to do the setup:upgrade so magento creates those new tables.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand the setup:upgrade part. My knowledge disconnect comes from people stating they are able to minimize downtime by doing all of this on a staging server, then rsync'ing files from staging to production, but this process does not account for new module deployment when db tables are updated/generated. So I guess you are saying that this process is not possible for new module deployment, and that you must go through this sometimes long and slow process on the production server? Including compilation and static file deployment... Something doesn't add up here.

Comment: Hmmm that sounds interesting. In theory it should be possible to sync some generated stuff. They could also manually create the tables manually through a query instead of using the module setup stuff. So to answer your question yes it might be possible. Its just a matter of proving the concept.

Comment: That is correct, you can sync generated files etc, so that part makes sense. I have read about companies who require basically zero downtime, and that this is achievable using Magento 2 (and some sort of continuous integration), so, in the context of this question, I would love to fully understand how this is possible. Finding this answer currently eludes me :-)